# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow.python.distribute.distribution_strategy_context'

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, module, gpu, generative-adversarial-network

For a while, I have been trying to use tensorflow with my GPU for a Deep Learning project. After installing cuda and cudNN (according to this link for version compatibility: ), I moved the three folders from the cudNN zip folder into the cuda folder. After adding the necessary paths, I restarted my PC, and now I am getting this error when I try to run my project. I am not sure how to get past this and potentially use my gpu with tensorflow. Here is the link to my project as well: https://github.com/HarrisonBounds/ML-Research

I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling different version of cuda and cudNN. I have also tried installing numba and using the jit decorator to use my gpu an alternative way. I am unsure what I expected, as I followed many online tutorials. The result of it all was many failed attempts at using my GPU for this project, which runs extremely slow without it (it uses GANs).